# $PATH looks corrupted, is my hunch about the fix right?

Tags: bash, path

I'm looking at my $PATH

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/gpiuser/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/gpiuser/Library/Android/sdk/toolsHOME/.npm/bin
```

And noting that last directory is not a directory. I'm guessing it should look like

```
      tools:Users/gpiuser/.npm/bin
```

instead of

```
       toolsHOME/.npm/bin
```

and that something went wrong with a node.js installation at some point.

So I look at my .bash_profile:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin

export
PATH=${PATH}:/Users/gpiuser/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/gpiuser/Library/Android/sdk/toolsHOME/.npm/bin
export
NODE_PATH=$HOME/.npm/lib/node_modules
```

and I THINK I should correct the file to reflect the above change and run source ~.bash_profile

Am I right?

Comment: You have posted `.bash_profile` so that we see line wraps where there are none.  I'm afraid to edit it because the source looks like `export` is on a separate line, which is a different error, but also an error.  Could you update to show the *precise* contents of this file as a code block, please?

Comment: That is the code block -- and there is a line break between the lines PATH and export, even now, in the working file adjusted according to grgarside's solution. My $PATH variable is complete with both sets of directories listed above so I can't see how export on a separate line twould be an error.

Comment: Have a look at this screen dump: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iMiTu.png -- using `>` instead of a four-line indent marks your text as an excerpt, not as a code block, and that means it's reflown to my screen width.

Comment: Gotcha. Four line indented now.

Comment: So you really do have the `export` statements on separate lines?  That would produce a huge amount of `declare -x` output on your terminal when you log in.  (There should be no need to `export PATH` explicitly because it is already exported.  If you want `NPM_PATH` to be exported, you need to move the `export` to the beginning of the line where you assign it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fix is missing a forward slash before Users, therefore `…tools:/Users/gpiuser/.npm/bin`.

It seems `…tools:$HOME/.npm/bin` was what was intended, but stating the literal path works too.